# Asp.net MVC Entity Framework best way to retrieve data in many to many relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a question about the best way to retrieve data from many to many relationships that have been set up via entity framework.

As a simple example, let's say I have two models:

1. Items
2. Categories

Let's say that this is a many-to-many relationship in which an item can have many categories and a category can belong to many items.

As far as I understand, I do not need to create a third model for the Item-Category relationship as this is handled by the entity framework itself.

Thus, once everything is set up and I have used scaffolding on both of the models I end up with code similar to this:

```
  public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TShirtWSMVC.Models.Item> Items { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TShirtWSMVC.Models.Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Now, I want to display to my view each item and its associated categories. 
I am aware that I can code similar to:

```
dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(//Query the conjunction table here)
```

I could also make a method named `AllCategoriesForItem(int itemID)` inside the database context class.

I was wondering if there are better options? Such as when using `dbContext.Items.ToList()` it automatically retrieving the categories for each item so the Categories list for each item isn't null.

Alternatively, is there a way to have the `ItemCategory` table represented in the application db context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace YourApp.Controllers
{
    public class YourController: Controller
    {
        //your db context
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = db.Items.Include(c => c.Categories);
            return View(list.toList());
        }
     }
}
```

That's your controller, now you have to use it on your view.